# Random Crashes Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ram, debian, crash

Every once in a while my Mem and CPU max out. In looking at the syslog I found

Jun 25 01:45:30 id-llc-projects CRON[29889]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)

this ran at the same time the Mem and CPU maxed out.

What is this command and how do I stop it?

Comment: it was the last thing on my syslog before system crashed/rebooted! still dont know what happened...

Answer (score 3):

*sar* - Collect, report, or save system activity information.

Type 'sar -A' to see the report about disk, memory, network for your machine.

To disable the cronjob, comment this lines:

```
$ grep debian-sa1 /etc/cron.d/sysstat
5-55/10 * * * * root command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1
59 23 * * * root command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 60 2
```

To disable the service, change this to "false"

```
$ grep ENABLED /etc/default/sysstat 
ENABLED="true"
```

Finally, stop the service:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/sysstat stop
```

Comment: `sar` is about statistics and will not contain information like what errors happened on an IO of an external HD, but may help on knowing what was happening at that time right? do you find it encumbersome to the cpu or HD?